# Passing more arguments to this type of python function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, parameter-passing

I figure this is pretty basic, but can't seem to figure out even how to ask google the right question.  I am using [this python websocket client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client) to make some websocket connections.  Let's just assume I'm using the code example similar to that page:

```
import websocket
import thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        ws.send("Hello")
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

So what I am trying to do is add more arguments to the `on_open` function, something like this:

```
def on_open(ws, more_arg):
    def run(*args):
        ws.send("Hello %s" % more_arg)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())
```

But i can't figure out how to pass these arguments in, so I tried in the main thread:

```
ws.on_open = on_open("this new arg")
```

But i get the error:

> TypeError: on_open() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

How am I going to pass these new arguments to my `on_open` function?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes both helped but I ended up liking your `partial` usage better, I will accept that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that you need to assign a callback. You are instead calling a function and passing the return value to `ws`, which is incorrect.

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to curry a function to a higher order one:

```
from functools import partial

func = partial(on_open, "this new arg")
ws.on_open = func
```

When `func` is invoked, it will invoke `on_open` with the first argument as `"this new arg"`, followed by any other arguments passed to `func`. Look at the implementation of `partial` in the doclink for more details.

Comment: thanks yes the term "callback" is i think what I was blanking on.  Thanks for this, although I have to say the lambda technique suggested by Danial Sanchez seems pretty pythonic.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Yeah... they're all the same. Personally, I don't like lambdas :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `lambda` to wrap the call:

```
ws.on_open = lambda *x: on_open("this new arg", *x)
```