# Save Websocket Data to Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, websocket

I'm trying to consume and save websocket data to a pandas DataFrame for other functions to use. However I'm very unfamiliar with them and originally got errors because I was trying to directly pass a df argument to on_message(). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673247/passing-more-arguments-to-this-type-of-python-function?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) link suggests using `partial` to add arguments but I am still getting a `error from callback <function on_message at 0x000002A098207510>: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment` error.

I realise there are better ways to process the data rather than a dataframe but I'd just like to get that working first. Thanks.

```
import websocket
import pandas as pd
import json
from functools import partial

# create empty df
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['foreignNotional','grossValue','homeNotional','price','side','size','symbol','tickDirection',
                          'timestamp','trdMatchID'])

def on_message(ws, message):
    msg = json.loads(message)
    print(msg)
    df = df
    df = df.append(msg)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    return

func = partial(on_message, df)
ws.on_message = func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD",
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have to modify an external object, and `pandas.DataFrame.append` does not allow in-place modification, you have to either make all function and `df` available as members of some class, so you would be able to write `self.df = self.df.append(msg)`, or use `global`:

```
import json

import pandas as pd
import websocket

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['foreignNotional', 'grossValue', 'homeNotional', 'price', 'side',
                           'size', 'symbol', 'tickDirection', 'timestamp', 'trdMatchID'])


def on_message(ws, message):
    msg = json.loads(message)
    print(msg)
    global df
    # `ignore_index=True` has to be provided, otherwise you'll get
    # "Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name" errors
    df = df.append(msg, ignore_index=True)


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)


def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD",
                                on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error, on_close=on_close)
    ws.run_forever()
```